# 'If' statement with the 'or' operator in PHP

Tags: php, operators

I'm trying to build up a PHP `if` statement with `or` ("||") operators, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
   $country_code = "example_country_code";

   if ($country_code != 'example_country_code' || !clientIscrawler()) {
       echo 'the script can be executed';
   }
   else {
       echo 'skipping';
   }
```

With the given example, it should be echoed skipping, but it doesn't happen like that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And *why* should it echo 'skipping'? Definitely not because of the country code.

Comment: What value is the value returned by `clientIscrawler()`?

Comment: what you get by `var_dump(!clientIscrawler());` ?

Comment: !clientIscrawler() is returning 1 or 0

Comment: Do you want `skipping` to be echoed when `clientCrawler()` is false *and* the country code is  not 'example_country_code'?

Comment: with false === clientIscrawler() seems to work, let me give another try

Comment: yes @Asad that would be the objective

Comment: @user1659575 In that case, you should use an `&&` operator, not `||`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the double negatives are giving you problems. Let's rewrite it to:

```
!($country_code == 'example_country_code') || !clientIscrawler()
```

This can be turned into an equivalent condition with `&&`:

```
!($country_code == 'example_country_code' && clientIscrawler())
```

By reversing the `if` you would get this:

```
if ($country_code == 'example_country_code' && clientIscrawler()) {
    echo 'skipping';
} else {
    echo 'the script can be executed';
}
```

Therefore, in your code, it will only print skipping if `clientIscrawler()` is truthy.

Comment: thanks a lot I have been changing a bit and seems to work !($country_code == 'example' || $country_code == 'example2' || clientIscrawler())

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple conditions with the OR operator, in which case you don't want the `if` statement to evaluate as true, the syntax is:

```
if(!($something == "something" || $something == 'somethingelse')){
    do stuff...
}
```

Here is an example:

```
$apples = array (
 1 => "Pink Lady",
 2 => "Granny Smith",
 3 => "Macintosh",
 4 => "Breaburn"
);

foreach($apples as $apple){

    // You don't want to echo out if the apple name is "Pink Lady" or "Macintosh"

    if(!($apple == "Pink Lady" || $apple == "Macintosh")){

        echo $apple."<br />";

    }
}

// Output is:
Granny Smith
Breaburn
```

Answer (score 0):

In your given code, it all depends on your function call

```
 !clientIscrawler()
```

You will be getting the `script can be executed` output only when your function call returns `FALSE`. I think it is returning `TRUE` right now, which is why you are not getting the desired output.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this can help you:

```
if ( ($country_code != 'example_country_code') || clientIscrawler() == false) {
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this way:

```
if ( ($country_code != 'example_country_code') || !clientIscrawler()) { ...
```